# Internet Explorer 9 Posts Forms Differently?

Tags: forms, html, post, internet-explorer-9

I've been using buttons for quite some time that are structured as follows:

```
<button type='submit'><em class='ui-icon ui-icon-disk'/><span>Save</span></button>
```

The  tag then uses the jquery-ui icons to show a disk image for the button. PROBLEM: As soon as users started using IE9, they were getting the server error:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (<em class=ui-icon)
```

I can only assume that IE9 is posting the form values differently - does anyone know how to stop the browser submitting certain form elements or how to resolve this issue?

Comment: IE9 posts the content of the button, try adding a `value` attribute or, have a look on this page and make IE9 behave like another version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Have you considered using an image button?

Comment: @Vince: Pardon my ignorance, but what is an image button? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

If you remove the `name` attribute from the button element then the form will not submit its value or the value of any element within it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type="image">` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, however, I dont want to replace the entire image of the button, just the button image :( What annoys me most about IE9 is how RANDOMLY I get the server error! The same form post will only cause the error 1/10 times...